# disable a link after click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have a number of links (A elements) STYLED AS buttons with class "btn" and when one of them is clicked, I want that particular button to be disabled. this code doesn't work:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).prop('disabled',true);
});
```

There are a gazillion tutorials for preventing the default event of a form submit button, and then disabling that, but that is not quite what I need...

Apparently, my `$this` isn't pointing to the correct object, or something =)

----------- UPDATE ---------------

SORRY, update above. The element I have is not a button, it is a link styled as a button...

Comment: can you reproduce it in stacksnippet or http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Try to return false at the end of the callback and check it again in case you are submitting form with normal post back. you can also try e.preventDefault() and check if it works.

Comment: seems to be working fine. You need to provide a minimal working example of your issue, and document what your expected behaviour is

Comment: don't try to disable the link.. try to update the href of that.. 
$(this).attr("href","javascript:void(0);");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't try to disable the Anchor tag. Try to set the href instead.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).off("click").attr('href', "javascript: void(0);");
   //add .off() if you don't want to trigger any event associated with this link
});
```

Comment: The .off("click") is working perfectly fine but when I am trying to use .on("click") to enable the anchor it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to stop defaultevent from links.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).prop('disabled',true);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$('a').css("pointer-events", "none");
```

Comment: worked in chrome, and all answers, including the accepted one, either does not work, or does not suit my need (and hence not tested)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used the following:

```
onclick="$(this).css('pointer-events', 'none');"
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).prop('disabled',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class='btn'>But1</button>
  <button class='btn'>But2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, the element is an <a> not a button, it was styled as a button so I fooled myself...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `this`, you can just specify your target by using its `id`.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#btn2').prop('disabled',true);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" class="btn">Button</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn">Button</button>
<button id="btn3" class="btn">Button</button>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I know, but I want an arbitrary function for all .btn

Comment: @MattWelander `when one of them is clicked, I want that particular button to be disabled.` From that sentence I thought only one specified button that should be disabled. So, if the case is all the buttons should be disabled, then your code works fine already.

Comment: No all buttons shouldn't be, only the clicked one, but when I write the code I don't know which button will get clicked so the code must be abstract in that sense

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/5243272

Answer (score 0):

This works (in chrome), but perhaps some drawbacks?

```
        $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
            if( $(this).prop('disabled') == true) {
                return false; 
            }

            $(this).prop('disabled',true);

        });
```

Comment: this should work fine but you can use `data('disabled', true)` instead of `prop('disabled', true)` to make sure it works across browser

Comment: btw the disabled did not work is mainly because as you have mentioned you are using <a> hyperlink element instead of button element which do not have a property named "disabled"

Comment: Based on here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a , `<a>` doesn't have disabled property. However, I think you can trick it by removing the href attribute and change the css instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('I have been clicked!');
    $(this).css('pointer-events', 'none').css('cursor', 'default');
  });
});
```

This will prevent any other further clicks on that link.

Answer (score 0):

If your Html like this

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.in/" target="_blank" class="test">This      is another paragraph.</a>
```

use below code :

```
$(".test").one("click", function() {
    var clas = $(this).attr("class");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("." + clas).removeAttr('href');
    }, 100);
});
```

If your Html like this

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.in/" target="_blank" class="test"> <button class="btn">This is another paragraph.</button></a>
```

use below code :

```
$(".btn").one("click", function() {
    var clas = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("." + clas).removeAttr('href');
    }, 100);
});
```